# Installing Yii composer asset plugin on composer

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php, yii-components

I am trying to install "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0" on windows 32bit composer but always failed.
Here is the message

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   Content-Length mismatch
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress]
>   [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev]
>   [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
>   [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

Anyone know what is the problem here? Please help
Thank you

Comment: Try `composer selfupdate` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update composer at first with

```
composer selfupdate
```

And be sure, you installing "fxp/composer-asset-plugin" globally, like [official install guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html) says:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
```

If you are using windows, try running composer from cmd "as Administator". To clarify, if you have access to global directory, run

```
composer global show -s
```

And check output directory manually